# Availability of the GET method to a HTTP Location resource

Tags: rest, http

After a `POST` request, there is generally a HTTP's header `Location` that inform the client about the location of the created resource.

Does this mean the URL of the `Location` have necessarily to be requested with the `GET` request?

Or does the HTTP client should first use the `OPTIONS` method before to eventually use the `GET` action?

In my opinion, this second way would be better, because it would allow the server to not necessary provide a `GET` action, unless needed.

Comment: How would the browser know which one to pick if the OPTIONS request came back with multiple supported methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The only code that *requires* you to use GET is 303 (See Other)**. 301 and 302 allow the client to change the response type from POST to GET, for historical reasons, but generally speaking, the client shouldn't do that.

This said, servers are never *required* to provide a resource when responding to GET requests. The only requirement is that GET requests must do no harm. **If you need to redirect to a resource but don't want to provide a GET response to that redirection, just have it return code 405 (Method Not Allowed) with the appropriate Allow header**. Because the Allow header contains the allowed methods for the resource, this eliminates the need to preface a GET request with an OPTIONS request: the client gets what it needs alongside the error message.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think to use this `Allow` header. Very useful.

Comment: The spec actually requires the `Allow` header when returning code 405.

Answer (score 0):

The type of request depends on the HTTP status code sent with the Location header.

301 and 302 statuses may trigger GET requests (for historical reasons).

303 statuses explicitly trigger GET requests.

307 and 308 statuses trigger whatever kind of request was used to ask for the redirected resource.

Further reading: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4

Comment: Another possible status header is 201 Created. The Location header for a 201 response may or may not need to be fetched. It's up to the client to decide if it wants to fetch the resource that it had just created. Usually the decision depends on an out of band knowledge of whether the server modifies the resource before creating the resource, whether the server returns the resource in the body of the 201, and whether the client actually will need to updated resource.